# Calendar date comparison in a SQLite query is not working for first day of the month

Tags: android, sqlite

I take the current date, then set the day of the month to 1.  Then, in the query, I say that the date already stored in database must occur after or on this date.  The dates being compared are in milliseconds as you'll see from the code.

My problem is when I create an entry in the database, and set the date for the first of the month, it is never included in the result for some reason.  However, if I simply set it to the 2nd of the current month, it works as intended.  I am hoping the error is somewhere surrounding this query.  At least if it all looks good to you, I'll know my logic must be wrong elsewhere.

EDIT:  The query in question is the query being set to cursor2 the second time (in the first for loop).

```
public void buildTable () {
    SQLiteDatabase db = BalanceDb.getInstance(this).getDB();
    String curCat = "", category = "", spent = "";
    double catTotal, percent, curBudget;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    long backDate = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    Cursor cursor1 = db.query(CategoriesDbContract.TblCategories.TABLE_NAME, 
                             null, null, null, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor2 = db.query(TransactionsDbContract.TblTransactions.TABLE_NAME,
                             null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor1.moveToFirst() == false) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No categories found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        for (int i = cursor1.getCount() - 1; i >=0; i--) {
            catTotal = 0;
            cursor1.moveToPosition(i);

            curCat = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    CategoriesDbContract.TblCategories.COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY));
            curBudget = cursor1.getDouble(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    CategoriesDbContract.TblCategories.COLUMN_NAME_BUDGET));

            cursor2 = db.query(TransactionsDbContract.TblTransactions.TABLE_NAME,
                           null, 
                           TransactionsDbContract.TblTransactions.COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY + "= '" + curCat + "'" +
                           "AND " + TransactionsDbContract.TblTransactions.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + ">=" + backDate, 
                           null, null, null, null);

            for (int j = cursor2.getCount() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

                cursor2.moveToPosition(j);

                catTotal += -1 * (cursor2.getDouble(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        TransactionsDbContract.TblTransactions.COLUMN_NAME_AMOUNT)));
            }

            percent = catTotal/curBudget * 100;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
            df.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
            String percStr = df.format(percent);

            category += cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    CategoriesDbContract.TblCategories.COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY)) + "\n";

            spent += percStr + "\n";
        }

        textCat.setText(category);
        textSpent.setText(spent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited answer according to The Rationalist solution.
The hour would be at the hour you call `cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);` you need to change

```
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 0);
```

Comment: Well, for whatever reason, this didn't work. But it did help point me in the right direction, in which I finally found the solution.  I just set the Calendar.DATE to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: You should write up your own answer and accept it, instead of accepting mine. Let me know if you do that otherwise I will edit my answer so that other people with the same problem who do not read comment can get the correct answer.